# What is the function of the 'errors' parameter to subprocess.Popen()?

Tags: python

The python [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) only mention the `errors` parameter in passing:

> If encoding or errors are specified, or universal_newlines is true, file objects for stdin, stdout and stderr are opened in text mode using the specified encoding and errors or the io.TextIOWrapper default.

I understand the usage of `text` and `universal_newlines`, which are synonyms.
I also understand the usage of `encoding`.

What is the function of the `errors` parameter? It appears to have been added in Python 3.6.  Is `errors` just a synonym of `encoding`?
If it is just a synonym, are there any published reasoning for this addition?

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation for [io.TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)? This has an entire paragraph about the `errors` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `errors` parameter is described in the linked documentation for [io.TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

> `errors` is an optional string that specifies how encoding and decoding errors are to be handled. Pass `'strict'` to raise a `ValueError` exception if there is an encoding error (the default of `None` has the same effect), or pass `'ignore'` to ignore errors. (Note that ignoring encoding errors can lead to data loss.) `'replace'` causes a replacement marker (such as `'?'`) to be inserted where there is malformed data. `'backslashreplace'` causes malformed data to be replaced by a backslashed escape sequence. When writing, `'xmlcharrefreplace'` (replace with the appropriate XML character reference) or `'namereplace'` (replace with `\N{...}` escape sequences) can be used. Any other error handling name that has been registered with `codecs.register_error()` is also valid.